# How to Hibernate in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: hibernate, ubuntu, swap, ubuntu-18.04, power-management

It seems like Hibernate function is not working properly on Ubuntu 18.04. I have tried with several commands like ***sudo pm-hibernate***, ***sudo systemctl hibernate*** etc. Nothing works.

Is hibernate also related to Hardware? My laptop RAM is 16GB and I have created the swap partition with the size of 24GB.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Better ask this question on http://askubuntu.com.

Comment: Thanks, @SamuelP. Just posted there.

Comment: Duplicate on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/): https://askubuntu.com/q/1031633/354350

Answer (score 0):

I searched high an low for a solution to this problem. My Dell E7450 simply failed to hibernate regardless of the many different methods I tried.  One day I stumbled upon this article which actually works!  Its a long series of steps so pay attention, it is the only method that actually works so follow these steps and you'll be hibernating to your hearts delight! (I can't take any credit for this one!):

https://fitzcarraldoblog.wordpress.com/2018/07/14/configuring-lubuntu-18-04-to-enable-hibernation-using-a-swap-file/